# Controlling/Specifying URIs for KML to Google Earth

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, kml, google-earth, data-uri

I have a Web application that generates a Google Earth KML file. I'm attempting to generate the download using URIs, to avoid having to make a trip to the server.

The problem is cross-browser. It works in Chrome, *almost* works in FireFox and appears not to execute at all in Internet Explorer.

Here's the code:

```
domKML = geItem.getKml(); 

uriContent = "data:application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml; charset=UTF-8'," + encodeURIComponent(domKML); 

window.open(uriContent, 'ROSE Download' + studyName);
```

By "Works" I mean that the when the invoking browser is Chrome, the data are downloaded and rendered within Google Earth (starting if it need be.)

By "Almost Works" I mean that when the browser is FireFox, the data are downloaded but the file extension is .part; and it refuses to go to Google Earth

And by "appears not to execute" I mean that IE sits there and sneers at me.

Any thoughts, oh wizards of the interwebz?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in IE as far as I know.

- In IE7 and lower there is no support for DataURI
- In IE8 the DataURI length limit is 32kb and Data URIs are supported only for images, links and css.
- In IE9 the DataURI length limit is 4gb but again can only be used for images, not for navigation or Javascript generated file downloads.

Also, in Firefox there is no way to set the extension for a DataURI, sorry.